# Minimum permission to view live data - Azure Kubernetes

Tags: azure, azure-aks

I have enabled Kubernetes RBAC authorization in all my Azure kubernetes clusters. Now I need to give permissions for viewing live data in containers tab

[image]

How can I do it? Which is the minimum premission needed?

Thanks

Comment: are you reffering to container logs?

Comment: I have edited my post. I added the image. I need to give permission to users to "view live data (preview)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand from my investigation, if you want to do it using Azure Built-in roles, you need the following three roles at the very least:

- **Reader** role assignment scoped to the **AKS cluster** to be able to discover the cluster
- **Azure Kubernetes Service Cluster User Role** role assignment scoped to the **AKS cluster** as mentioned in the note atop the page in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/insights/container-insights-live-logs). This is needed to allow access to `Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters/listClusterUserCredential/action` API call. This API call lists the cluster user credentials.
- **Log Analytics Contributor** role assignment scoped to the Log Analytics workspace associated to the AKS cluster. This is needed to execute an Analytics query for data, i.e., perform a `/workspaces/{workspaceId}/query` API call. More [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/loganalytics/query/execute).

This should let one pull up the live data for containers. If not comfortable with this approach, you might also create a Custom Role allowing only those exact actions.

Hope this helps!