# How to access Azure Kubernetes audit admin logs with out admin permission or with limited permissions

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks

How to access Azure Kubernetes audit admin logs with out admin permission or with limited permissions, I need different ways to access Kubernetes audit admin logs

Trying to acces logs with minimal permission with out intervention of admin team

Comment: Accessing AKS audit logs without admin permissions or with limited permissions is challenging, as audit logs typically require higher-level access for security reasons. However, you might consider these approaches: Request specific RBAC roles that have read-only access to logs and using Azure Monitor-> Logs-> [aks audit logs](https://i.imgur.com/YphHKR8.png)

Comment: Check if you have these [Role](https://i.imgur.com/USbjDOc.png)

Answer (score 1):

Accessing Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS) audit logs without admin permissions or with limited permissions is challenging, as audit logs typically require higher-level access for security reasons. However, you might consider these approaches:

1. **Role-Based Access Control (RBAC)**: Request specific RBAC roles that have read-only access to logs. You may not get full audit log access, but you can access a subset of the logs based on your role's permissions.
   [image: Role]
2. **Azure Monitor**: If AKS audit logs are integrated with Azure Monitor, you might access some log data if you have permissions to view Monitor resources.
   [image: aks audit logs]

accessing audit logs usually requires elevated permissions due to the sensitive nature of the data they contain. Reader access is basically '*read only*' therefore you should be able to view the logs.

[image]

```
AKSAudit
| where ResponseStatus.code != 401  // Exclude unauthorized responses
| mv-expand SourceIps               // Expand the list of SourceIp entries into individual rows
| summarize Count = count() by SourceIp = tostring(SourceIps), ResourceId = _ResourceId
| sort by Count desc
```

FYI, these audit queries are predefined by default, you can even edit them and customize it as per your own needs by using load to editor option

[image]

Reference Document-

[MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/containers/container-insights-log-query#resource-logs)

[Similar SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58170654/minimum-permission-to-view-live-data-azure-kubernetes)